# Can't remove treeview item in c++

Tags: c++, treeview

I'm adding item in a treeview like that:

```
TVINSERTSTRUCT tvinsert;
tvinsert.hParent = selectedtreeitem;
tvinsert.hInsertAfter = TVI_LAST;
tvinsert.item.pszText = name;
tvinsert.item.mask = TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_IMAGE | TVIF_SELECTEDIMAGE;
tvinsert.item.iImage = 0;
tvinsert.item.iSelectedImage = 1;

HTREEITEM ti=(HTREEITEM)SendDlgItemMessage(_hSelf, IDC_TREE1, TVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)&tvinsert);
```

It works perfectly, but when I try to remove like that:

```
TreeView_DeleteItem(_hSelf, tvinsert);
```

It doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

It works with that:

SendDlgItemMessage(_hSelf, IDC_TREE1, TVM_DELETEITEM, TVGN_CARET, (LPARAM)tvinsert);